# Permission (Verb) vs Permit (Verb)?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering how exactly the verb-version of "permission" works, and if my usage of it has been correct at all. I've mostly been using it in a technical/computer-related context, however whenever I used it as anything other than a noun, I got the squiggly lines, which made me think twice about keeping to use it. For example: "Something needs to be permissioned" sounds very different to me than "Something needs to be permitted", but perhaps it isn't different, but just plain wrong.

I've used it in various other forms as well, "permissioning", "permission" (verb), etc. To me, permission as a verb is about access control, which is somewhat bigger than just "to permit", which is strictly about the "allowing" side of things.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: In the IT context things are usually "granted permission" or "given permission".

Comment: @KillingTime But that's about the explicit act of allowing something, similar to how the verb "permit" works. The way I was (wrongly, I guess?) using "to permission" is for it to symbolize access control both ways. So for example "X should be permissioned for Y" was my usage of meaning "X should have means of controlling access permissions in the context of doing Y, which it does't have yet" (Similar to how https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/permissioning#:~:text=Noun,or%20result%20of%2C%20granting%20authorization. works)

Comment: @NewJob Please add your usage of *permission* as a verb to your question. You can [edit] it easily.

Comment: Please add a dictionary endorsement that 'permission [verb]' is in the lexicon. You **can't** (acceptably) verb every noun. *'I unusualnessed it.'

Comment: permitting can be a whole other bag of tricks. As in: construction permits.

Comment: You get licensed at this window, then you get permissioned across the street at the Construction Permits window.

Comment: The field of IT makes up its own terms as it goes along, but often the new thing extends to other speakers of English slowly, or never.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Not sure what you mean. I described the topic in the title and the usage in the body, what is missing?

Answer (score 3):

**Permission** as a verb is not in Merriam-Webster or Lexico (Oxford). However it is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/permission#Verb) with the meaning

> **permission** [verb] [transitive]: To grant or obtain authorization for.

They give the example sentence (from a 2003 guide to writing textbooks):

> - *Photographs also must be permissioned and credited, although a corpus of copyright-free images does exist online.*

This could be paraphrased "You must obtain permission and provide credit for photographs." It would be harder to paraphrase it with "photographs" as the subject: "Photographs must have permission and credit" would be possible but does not convey the fact that permission should be explicitly obtained rather than just being something that already exists.

The verb **permit** [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/permit)] means

- to allow something to happen or
- to grant authorisation for something;

it is usually used with an activity or action, e.g. "a feature permitting remote control", "permitting these procedures", "permit the licensed sale of...", "The parent is not permitted to give blanket consent". It is not used with an object that may require permission to use, unlike the verb *permission*.

So it appears the main difference is that the verb *permission* typically takes as its object some entity to which something can only be done with permission (e.g. a copyrighted photograph), while *permit* takes as its object an action which requires permission.